# firebase aync await getting null object in try catch

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on firebase api for realtime database, I am using async await, but it is not working for that i have used try catch in node js, I can see i am getting status 0, so it invokes catch, but in catch i am getting error as null object, can anyone please help me why i am not getting proper error in that ? even my try code is correct still it invokes catch, here i have added my whole code, can anyone please look in my code, and help me to resolve this error ?  i am getting this response,

Response :

```
{"status":0,"data":{}}
```

API :

```
export const check_await = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      const body_data = req.body;
      const db = admin.database();
      const org_id = body_data.company_id;
      const highfive_id = body_data.highfive_id;
      const ref = db.ref("organizations/" + org_id + "/highfive/" + highfive_id);

      const snapshot = await ref.on("value");
      const data = snapshot.val();
      cors(req, res, () => { return res.send({ 'status': 1, 'data': data, 'msg': 'High five feed record get successfully' }); });
    } else {
      cors(req, res, () => { return res.send({ 'status': 0, 'msg': "Only POST method is allowed" }); });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    cors(req, res, () => { return res.send({ 'status': 0, 'data': error }); });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i resolved the issue, i need to use `once` instead of `on`, here is my full code of it,

```
export const check_await = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      const body_data = req.body;
      const db = admin.database();
      const org_id = body_data.company_id;
      const highfive_id = body_data.highfive_id;
      const ref = db.ref("organizations/" + org_id + "/highfive/" + highfive_id);

      const snapshot = await ref.once("value");
      const data = snapshot.val();
      cors(req, res, () => { return res.send({ 'status': 1, 'data': data, 'msg': 'High five feed record get successfully' }); });
    } else {
      cors(req, res, () => { return res.send({ 'status': 0, 'msg': "Only POST method is allowed" }); });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    cors(req, res, () => { return res.send({ 'status': 0, 'data': error.message }); });
  }
});
```